# Longest common subsequence (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I've been struggling with this for a while. I'm solving the longest common subsequence problem in Haskell as a learning exercise.

I have a function `f1` that is passed two Ints `i` and `j`, and a function `f2`. `f1` builds a two dimensional list so that the (i,j) location in the list is equal to `f2 i j`.

Now I'm trying to write a function called `lcs` that takes two Strings `s1` and `s2` and finds the longest common subsequence using `f1` for memoization.

I'm not exactly sure how to set this up. Any ideas?

Code:

```
f1 :: Int -> Int -> (Int -> Int -> a) -> [[a]]

f2 :: Int -> Int -> a

lcs:: String -> String -> Int
```

Comment: I don't completely understand what `f1` and `f2` do. Is it possible to post the code? Here are the type signatures as I understand them: `f1 :: Int -> Int -> a`; `f2 :: Int -> Int -> a`. What's the difference?

Comment: @AndresRiofrio: Maybe xcross means `f1 :: (Int -> Int -> a) -> [[a]]` s.t. `f1 f2 !! i !! j == f2 i j`.

Comment: @rampion: How about `f1 :: Int -> Int -> (Int -> Int -> a) -> [[a]]` and `f2 :: Int -> Int -> a`? So that `f1 _ _ f2 !! i !! j == f2 i j`.

Comment: @AndresRiofrio added some code. Thanks guys.

Comment: Solve recursively first (as *defined* (not implemented) on wikipedia), don't worry about the exponential time.  Then, after that is implemented correctly, go back and memoize (there are various techniques for this, but that's fodder for another SO question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the `Int` parameters of `f1` are some sort of bounds? Remember that using lists give you the benefit of not needing to specify bounds (because of laziness), but it costs you slow access times.

This function should do what you want `f1` to do (memoize a given function):

```
memo :: (Int -> Int -> a) -> (Int -> Int -> a)
memo f = index where
  index x y = (m !! x) !! y
  m         = [[f x y|y <- [0..]]|x <- [0..]]

-- memoized version of f2
f2' = memo f2
```